# How do I place an image in the same window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, window, frame

I am trying to place the image in the same window but it opens up in a new window and I can't figure out why. I've tried google but couldn't find anything to help me. How do I specify the image should be placed in the initial window that opens up instead of its own separate window?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import io
import base64
# Import the function for downloading web pages
from urllib import urlopen

# Import the regular expression function
from re import findall

# Import the Tkinter functions
from Tkinter import *

# Import Python's HTML parser
from HTMLParser import *
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
        root = tk.Tk()

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def createimage(self):  
            # a little more than width and height of image
            w = 520
            h = 320
            x = 80
            y = 100
            # use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
            # this GIF picture previously downloaded from tinypic.com
            image_url = "http://i46.tinypic.com/r9oh0j.gif"
            image_byt = urlopen(image_url).read()
            image_b64 = base64.encodestring(image_byt)
            self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_b64)
            # create a white canvas
            #topframe = Frame(root)
            cv = tk.Canvas(bg='white')
            cv.pack(side='top', expand='yes')
            # put the image on the canvas with
            # create_image(xpos, ypos, image, anchor)
            cv.create_image(10, 10, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    root.geometry("400x300")
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    main.createimage()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are explicitly creating two root windows. Count the number of times `tk.Tk()` appears in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Why does it open up in a separate window?

You need to pass a master to each constructor. This should be the widget (Tk, Frame, Toplevel, Canvas, ...) that the new widget should be placed inside. Like this:

```
tk.Canvas(master = self, g='white')
tk.PhotoImage(master = self, data=image_b64)
```

When the master is destroyed, widgets with it as master are also destroyed.

### 2. In which window does it open up?

Tkinter has the default root, the first window which is created. This window is used for any widget you do not pass a master to.

i.e. the first `root = tk.Tk()`

Comment: When the initial window is started another window is then opened with the image inside but I am wanting the image to be opened in the first window without a second.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Try to add `master = self` at the appropriate locations. What is your outcome, when you change the code?

Comment: I've realized that I was calling tk.Tk() a second time in my class. When I added the master = self to it, it fixed the problem but when I removed the call to tk.Tk() I ended up not needing to specify the master anymore as it just defaulted to the correct window. Thank you very much, you've helped me a lot.

Comment: "This window is used for any widget you do not pass a master to." is not a true statement. Tkinter will automatically create a root window the _first_ time you create a widget and don't have a root window. Once a root window has been created, tkinter won't automatically create more.